# NuGetCmdletUnhandledException seen while trying to install Fluent library in VS

Tags: azure, visual-studio, installation, fluent

When I'm trying to install the Fluent package using PM in a ASP.NET app of Visual Studio using the command:
**Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent -Version 1.37.1**

The following error occurs:

**Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent 1.37.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Unsupported,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or
content files that are compatible with that framework.**

```
At line:1 char:2
+  Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent -Version 1.37.1
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Kindly help in resolving this exception.

Comment: hi, could my solution solve this problem? Look forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the cache packages in

`C:\Users\{userName}\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.management.fluent`

and

`.obj` folder in project directory.

Then restart visual studio and re-install it in PM.